# Datagridview show no data vb.net with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

```
Public Sub LoadAllTable_Items_InDirect(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal calstate As String)    
  Dim dt As New DataTable    
  Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter    
  dt.Clear()    
  da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from ItemsView  where " & calstate & " = 'True'", sql.sqlcon)    
  da.Fill(dt)    
  dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False    
  dgv.DataSource = dt    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked with the result of your select statement in SSMS? Also, your query should be non SQL Server injectable. So, parameterized your query.

Comment: Did you add columns to your grid in the designer? Did you set the `DataPropertyName` property of each column? You have explicitly told the grid not to generate columns automatically so, if you haven't done those things, why would you expect to see any data? If you have done those things, what value is returned by that `Fill` call?

Comment: it was my mistake I made a column called item_state which is true or false, it is true when we add data and false when we delete data  ....my mistake that I made it add false to the clam in the add statement...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code to bind the datagridview in VB.Net you can compare and correct if any part is missing in your code.

I think you are missing the code of `add columns` part as shown in my sample code.

```vb
Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim constring As String = "Data Source=.\SQL2005;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User id = sa;password=pass@123"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)

                    'Set AutoGenerateColumns False
                    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

                    'Set Columns Count 
                    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3

                    'Add Columns
                    dataGridView1.Columns(0).Name = "CustomerId"
                    dataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Customer Id"
                    dataGridView1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "CustomerID"

                    dataGridView1.Columns(1).Name = "Name"
                    dataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Contact Name"
                    dataGridView1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "ContactName"

                    dataGridView1.Columns(2).Name = "Country"
                    dataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Country"
                    dataGridView1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "Country"
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```